# C# .NET WinForm: Even Handler Method Name defined in XML and then Call in the code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying to do this:

1. Background of this question:

   - I am coding using WinForm (not WPF intentionally).
   - I will have set of controls, such as: set of ComboBoxes, set of Buttons, and so on, on my form.
   - each controls (although the same type, i.e. each comboboxes, each buttons, and so on) will behave differently from the same events. For example: combobox A's selectedIndexChanged will have a different definition, compare to combobox B's selectedIndexChanged.
2. What I'm trying to do:

   - I define an XML File (the following is simplified to make it easier to understand):

   `<EVENTS>
     <COMBOBOX_A>
      <SelectedIndexChanged METHOD_NAME="COMBOBOX_A_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
     </COMBOBOX_A>
     <COMBOBOX_B>
      <SelectedIndexChanged METHOD_NAME="COMBOBOX_B_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
     </COMBOBOX_B>
    </EVENTS>`

   - I can parse easily to get the method name from this XML file.
   - Once I get the method name, then I would like to hook-up that method with the associated events. and this is where my question is at Section 4 below.
3. Reason of why I'm doing it this way.

   - I want to make it as generic as possible (in a way), so that I can plug and play later on without modifying much of the code. For example: Only need to modify business logic layer (where the specific event handler definition is), than the generic control creation code.
   - Now, I know, this is what WPF is all about, but I intentionally to do it in WinForm.
4. Finally, my question:

   - I've been researching that it is possible to do it by using "Reflection" as suggested on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976(v=vs.110).aspx
   - But, is there a simpler way to achieve it?

(kind of Pseudo-Code)

```
ComboBox A = new ComboBox(); 
A.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandlers(xmlNode.Attributes["METHOD_NAME"].Value);
```

... and in some other part of the code:

```
public void COMBOBOX_A_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e){...}
```

so, in short, I really need to learn for a way to hook up an event handler by passing a method name in a string type, in which the method's definition is defined on the business logic layer.

Thanks!!!

Comment: try use [Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/system.reflection/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a private method for your ComboBox in your class like this:

```
private void COMBOBOX_A_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {...}
```

Let's get the class' MethodInfo from the name you have got from your xml:

```
var methods = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo methodInfo = methods.Single(m => m.Name == xmlNode.Attributes["METHOD_NAME"].Value); 
// .Single will throw an exception if there's more than one element found. 
// I suppose the value of ["METHOD_NAME"] in your xml is: COMBOBOX_A_SelectedIndexChanged

// Get the handler from the method info     
EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), this, methodInfo);

// Assign the handler
A.SelectedIndexChanged += handler;
```

Should work fine.